# Corda: many depended transaction in one flow can lead to inconsistency

Tags: transactions, consistency, corda

I have two transactions in flow. Second transaction are depend on first. Example scenario is:

1. First transaction ended successfully
2. Based on results form first transaction I create a second one
3. Second transaction fail for some reasons

I'm worry about consistency here. I need to keep this two separated transactions and results from both transactions should be persisted. Is there any built in Corda mechanism that allow us to rollback changes from first transaction?

Answer (score 0):

No, all transactions are final.

It's hard to suggest a solution here because the question doesn't detail your use-case. But perhaps you should combine the two transactions into one, possibly using confidential identities (i.e. anonymous public keys) to obscure each participant's identity.

**EDIT:** In the scenario you describe in your comment below, you have two transactions:

- Tx1, requiring signatures from A and B
- Tx2, requiring signatures from B and C

If A signs Tx1 and sends it to B, and C signs Tx2 and sends it to B, then B can make sure they only sign and send Tx1 for notarisation if they receive Tx2 signed by C first (and vice-versa).

However, this requires trusting B to only notarise Tx1 if they have a signed Tx2 (and vice-versa).

Comment: I consider one transaction, but then I have another problem. The use case is that I have three parties (let's call them A, B and C). In first transaction I want involve A and B. But second transaction has to involve only B and C. If I correctly understand transactions during signing, if I have one transaction all participants will get this transaction with copy of data.